# Janus GridEx - Retrieve sub-tables on demand

Tags: linq-to-sql, janus

I have a client-server app using Janus GridEx and Linq2Sql.

I have a grid that has one sub-table; Invoices (root) and Invoice Items (sub).

I would like to only retrieve invoice items when the invoice row is expanded..

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Yes , I have done this with EntityFramework (WinForm) , it should works for LinqToSql

First you need to Add a property to your Invoice class, use "partial" to do this

```
partial class Invoice
{
    public List<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItemList { get { return this.InvoiceItems.ToList();} }

}
```

then add a Child table for this property to your gridex.
if you have lazy loading and proxy 'ON' and did not dispose your context,you must have not any other problem